# Rename, Group Objects, Group groups

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript, 3ds

ObjectMain
-SubObjectX_A1
-SubObjectX_A2
-SubObjectX_A3
-SubObjectY_A1
-SubObjectY_A2
-SubObjectY_A3

-SubObjectXB_A1

-SubObjectXB_A2

-SubObjectXB_A3

-SubObjectYB_A1

-SubObjectYB_A2

-SubObjectYB_A3

How do i change A1 A2 A3 to AA1 AA2 AA3?

Then group them all by SubObjectX or SubObjectY?

Then Group the Grouped Objects into
GroupX?

is this possible with a single script or a button?

Try many scripts but always failed to find the right one.